# Internet is not working when rndis device is connected in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, ethernet

I have a Windows 10 PC with Ethernet plugged in and internet was working initially. My internet stopped working when I connect my embedded linux device via USB. I am using that device via rndis(Ethernet over USB). Help me in this issue. I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Edit:
Here is the `route print` output.

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 28...00 15 5d 36 3e 28 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 11...54 05 db 99 ba 0b ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
 14...36 e3 f9 24 31 b1 ......Remote NDIS Compatible Device
  7...b0 7d 64 4a 2b 0e ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 17...b2 7d 64 4a 2b 0d ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 16...fe 0c 8a f0 5a b4 ......ZeroTier Virtual Port
  8...b0 7d 64 4a 2b 0d ......Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.136     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   25.255.255.254    172.17.17.112  10034
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.242     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      169.254.1.1     169.254.1.10     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      169.254.1.10    281
     169.254.1.10  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.1.10    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.1.10    281
      172.17.17.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.17.17.112    291
    172.17.17.112  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.17.17.112    291
    172.17.17.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.17.17.112    291
      172.31.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.31.48.1    271
      172.31.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.31.48.1    271
    172.31.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.31.48.1    271
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.242    291
    192.168.1.136  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.242  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.242    291
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.242    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.242    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.17.17.112    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      169.254.1.10    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.31.48.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.242    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.17.17.112    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.1.10    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.31.48.1    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 16    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 28    271 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    291 fe80::2020:ca6:9da9:3893/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 fe80::81e1:9b94:8411:7328/128
                                    On-link
 28    271 fe80::dd5b:14e1:679c:73ce/128
                                    On-link
 16    291 fe80::f5fe:7ec7:d7f8:57cd/128
                                    On-link
 14    281 fe80::f8fe:8377:7ee:82d2/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 16    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 28    271 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This can be a routing problem. If the USB ethernet device is used as default gateway than all external (destination server is not located in any of your local networks) will use the new adapter instead of the correct adapter that is connected to the network with internet connection.

Comment: Please provide the output of `route print` with the RNDIS device connected.

Comment: @Robert how to check if USB ethernet device is the default gateway?

Comment: @DanielB I have added the `route print` output

Comment: You seem to have an IP address in the 192.168.1.x subnet on two different interfaces which would explain the non-working internet. Check `ipconfig` have configured this subnet.

Comment: That is because of the WiFi interface. I have connected to the router via WiFi as well. That's why. I don't think that is the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand you have two internet sources now the primary eth and the secondary is the linux device,
did you try isolate the linux device only by disabling the primary eth ?
also did you try running win 10 troubleshooting tool ?
is the linux device detected as an adapter ? if so try disabling and enabling it
finally if still not working try using it on a different PC and see

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have one internet source which is the physical ethernet. Other device is my embedded device which provides only the ip to communicate with it.

Comment: the linux device is providing internet or just a user ? 
what is the gateway of your working internet source if its 192.168.1.1
try, 
route delete 0.0.0.0  
then, 
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1